# ¿Por qué una edición del AP a su propia pregunta aparece en la cola de revisión?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas

En la cola de revisión de Ediciones sugeridas acabo de encontrarme con esta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/171322

En ella, el usuario:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/138933/mack-programmer

Hace una revisión a la pregunta:

[como obtener el penultimo registro de un grupo mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/288454/83)

Que inicialmente redactó el usuario:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/138933/mack-programmer

Como veis, el usuario que sugiere y el que redactó la pregunta es el mismo, por lo que la edición debería ser inmediata y sin que medie ninguna revisión.

Pongo los enlaces directamente para comprobar que efectivamente se trata del mismo usuario, con el mismo identificador (a veces parecen el mismo pero no lo son, pues uno está registrado y otro no y cosas así).

Mirando en la [actividad del usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/138933/mack-programmer?tab=activity) aparecen ambas acciones: preguntar y sugerir edición.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estos casos habitualmente se dan cuando se ha producido una unión (merge) de usuarios.

Vamos a analizar como ejemplo el caso que mencionas.

Imaginemos un usuario que por alguna razón tiene dos usuarios diferentes (uno sin registrar, y otro registrado). Dicho usuario realiza una pregunta con el usuario sin registrar, pero la sugerencia de edición la hace con el usuario registrado.

Como para el sistema son dos usuarios diferentes, la edición pasa a la cola de ediciones sugeridas.

Posteriormente, se produce una unión (merge) de ambos usuarios por ejemplo por petición del usuario. En ese caso, el id del usuario que hizo la pregunta y el del que hizo la sugerencia se convierten en el mismo. Sin embargo, el sistema no aprueba automáticamente la edición, por lo que se da el caso que has observado.

Como curiosidad, ahora el usuario ya podrá aprobar su propia sugerencia (eso si, sin recibir reputación por ello) -> [Suggesting and approving an edit on own post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165784)

Comment: Muchas gracias por investigarlo, por hacerlo tan rápido y reparar también en este caso particular de que el usuario podría aprobar su propia sugerencia de edición.

Comment: @fedorqui no es todo merito mio, hice una consulta en la sala de profesores tambien ;)